# How to open another tab with a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I've used jquery-ui tabs in a page. But I want, if someone clicks the link "Click me" in Tab1, it will automatically open the Tab2 for him. I want the link "Click me" to work as same as the Tab2 option works. How can I do that?
My codes are given below

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Homepage</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery_ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">

  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery_ui.js"></script>

  <script>

    $( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    } );

  </script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab_one">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab_two">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab_three">Tab3</a></li>

    <div id="tab_one">
        <p>Something about Tab1</p>
        <p><a href="">Click me</a></p>
    </div>

    <div id="tab_two">
        <p>Something about Tab2</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tab_three">
        <p>Something about Tab3</p>
    </div>

  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it will help you for custom click [jquery-ui-tabs-with-nextprevious](https://css-tricks.com/jquery-ui-tabs-with-nextprevious/)

```
$('#my-text-link').click(function() { // bind click event to link
    $tabs.tabs('select', 2); // switch to third tab
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you specify where and how to use this code? I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Oh sorry. I didn't notice that link. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

use `target="_blank"` attribute in your anchor tag, like

```
<li><a target="_blank" href="#tab_one">Tab1</a></li>
```

Comment: Seems that OP asks another question, by «tab» he refers to a tab inside a page, not the browser tab.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
 <p><a href="#tab_two">Click me</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the id of tab two in href tag of anchor element.

```
<div><a href="#tab_two">Click here to open tab 2</a></div>
```

Comment: this will not target the tab

Answer (score 1):

```
try this..

<li><a href="#"  onclick="window.open('your_page.php','newwindow', config='height=700, width=1200, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no,location=no, directories=no, status=no')" class="button yellow">Tab1</a></li>
```

using this link you can open new window with new page.

Answer (score 1):

on the click event of the "Click me" button

Add the below code to acheive it.

```
$("a[href='#tab_two']").trigger("click");
```

This should work for you.